# MongoDB converts number to string in scientific notation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, tostring, scientific-notation

I want to get full number as a `String`, but instead `"1490650000000"` it returns scientific notation `"1.49065e+12"`

Here's how I try to convert it:

```
{$substr: ["$myNumber", 0, -1]};
```

Any ideas how to prevent it?

**Note:**
I'm using v3.6 and can't upgrade to use `$toString` (thanks mlab).

Answer (score 9):

### You can try as below.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{ $addFields: { "strFld": {$toString: {$toLong:"$numberFiled"}}} },
])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have mongodb 4.0 then you can use [**`$toLong`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "myNumber": {
        "$toLong": "$myNumber"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: "Also I'm using **v3.6** and can't update to use $toString (thanks mlab)."
Unfortunately I can't use 4.0

Comment: Then you have to do this with JavaScript because there is no operator till 4.0 which can convert number to string